# Find issued ram through memory address

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-management

my pc sometimes get memory issue with error like this or just hanging some seconds...

```
---------------------------
Unexpected error
---------------------------
An error has occurred. MPC-HC will close now.

Exception:
ACCESS VIOLATION

Crashing module:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispig.inf_amd64_c0e159863e7afdde\nvd3dumx.dll
Offset: 0xDD216748, Codebase: 0x7FF775610000
The thread 628 tried to write memory at address 0x16728


---------------------------
OK
---------------------------
```

I have 2 physical ram, this occurs often while memory are 70% full,

[image: I have 2 Slot]

[image]

I want to know which memory have issue and so replace it,

There are a way to know?! or just replace 2 of them?!

Also maybe this is not physical ram issue and OS issue?!

Comment: `The thread 628 tried to write memory at address 0x16728` usually indicates not a RAM problem but a software bug.

Comment: If you suspect a RAM problem, run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) over night, for as long as you can.

Comment: “There are a way to know?” - Sure; Run MemTestx86 or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, this is an error caused by MPC-HC writing to a protected area of RAM, *not* an issue with the physical RAM modules.

- First, get the *latest* version of MPC-HC [from the development site](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases) (v. 1.9.22 on the day the question was asked), *not* from a third-party. Probably, you want the [full 64-bit installation file](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases/download/1.9.22/MPC-HC.1.9.22.x64.exe).
- Second, check that you have sufficient disk space for virtual RAM, i.e., memory moved to the SSD or HDD when physical RAM is insufficient for the current operation(s). Also [set virtual memory to an appropriate size](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/how-to-increase-virtual-memory-in-windows-10-a/46dacaf5-15cf-4f5d-9d5a-cba1401ae4c9). My own preference is to set the size manually, somewhere between 0.2 and 1.5 times the size of physical RAM, and to set *Initial size* and *Maximum size* the same, to avoid fragmenting the page file. (**N.B.** this seems to be an area with many differing opinions, so *caveat user* and feel free to experiment,)

[image: Setting Virtual Memory]

- If this *does not* resolve the issue, try to [repair the operating system files with DISM and SFC](https://www.techbout.com/repair-windows-system-files-using-sfc-dism-12162/), because all applications depend on various Windows libraries, which might be damaged, assigning memory to a protected area.
- You [can also try a RAM test application](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/how-to-test-ram), such as Windows 10 built-in  [Memory Diagnostic tool](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-test-for-bad-memory-ram-in-windows/) or a free third-party tool, such as [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/).